# Соответствует ли следующий код БЭМ?

Tags: бэм

Соответствует ли следующий код БЭМ?

```
<div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar__container wrapper">
                    <div class="navbar__menu">
                        <div class="navbar__menu-title"></div>
                        <div class="navbar__menu-categories">
                            <div class="navbar__menu-category">
                                <a href="#" class="navbar__menu-category-title"></a>
                                <div class="navbar__menu-subcategories">
                                    <a href="#" class="navbar__menu-subcategory"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вполне, так как у вас имеется вложенность. Так как нет модификаторов, то к ним не придраться

https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/